# Why works not Swedish characters in arguments from the command line with NetFSMountURLSync?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I have tried my first Swift program. It is meant to be run from a shell script with arguments and mount server volumes. When I start the program from Xcode having arguments with Swedish characters in the volume name (å, ä, ö, for example), the program works as it should. If I start the program from the command line with arguments with Swedish characters in the volume name, mounting fails, it creates a folder at mount point with the correct name in the "/Volumes".

Why does not the argument with Swedish characters works from the command line?

Code:

```
import Foundation
import NetFS

func mountShare(serverAddress: String, shareName: String, userName: String, password: String) {
    let fm = FileManager.default
    let mountPoint = "/Volumes/".appendingFormat(shareName)
    var isDir : ObjCBool = false
    if fm.fileExists(atPath: mountPoint, isDirectory: &isDir) {
        if isDir.boolValue {
            unmount(mountPoint, 0)
            print("Unmounted: \(mountPoint)")
        }
    }
    let sharePathRaw = "\(serverAddress)/\(shareName)"
    let sharePathWithPercentEscapes = sharePathRaw.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
    let sharePath = NSURL(string: sharePathWithPercentEscapes!)
    let kNAUIOptionKey = "UIOption"
    let kNAUIOptionNoUI = "NoUI"
    let mount_options = NSMutableDictionary()
    mount_options[kNAUIOptionKey] = kNAUIOptionNoUI
    NetFSMountURLSync(sharePath as CFURL!, nil, userName as CFString!, password as CFString!, mount_options, nil, nil)
}

let argCount = CommandLine.argc
if argCount == 5 {
    let serverUrl = CommandLine.arguments[1]
    let shareName = CommandLine.arguments[2]
    let userName = CommandLine.arguments[3]
    let password = CommandLine.arguments[4]
    mountShare(serverAddress: "\(serverUrl)", shareName: "\(shareName)", userName: "\(userName)", password: "\(password)")
} else {
    print("Wrong number of arguments.")
}
```

Example starting program from command line that works:

```
mountVolume "afp://my.server.com" "myVolume" "user" "password"
```

Example starting program from command line that not works:

```
mountVolume "afp://my.server.com" "myVolumeÅÄÖ" "user" "password"
```

More info:
I have tried to print out all the variables for comparing values when I ran the program from Xcode alternative the command line and no difference. However, NetFSMountURLSync exit with code 2 instead of 0 on the command line.

Comment: When run from the command line, what is the actual value for `shareName`?

Comment: I have a test volume named "myVolumeÅÄÖ".

Comment: That's not what I asked. When you actually run your program without Xcode, what is the actual value of the `shareName` variable? Based on the comment you posted below the answer, it would seem your issue is being caused by an optional value.

Comment: I do not know if I understand you correctly, but the mount point in the answer "/ Volumes / Optional (" myVolume ")" was when I added "encodedShareName" according to the response. Without "encodedShareName" creates an empty folder in / Volumes/ with the right name but the server volume is not mounted if it contains Å, Ä, Ö.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you first escape all the special characters in the relevant part of your connection string before passing it to NSURL's init ?

```
let encodedShareName = shareName.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
let sharePathRaw = "\(serverAddress)/\(encodedShareName!)"
```

Comment: It works either from Xcode or the command line regardless of characters. The mount point is named "/ Volumes / Optional (" myVolume ").

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the Optional. I've modified the response to read `let sharePathRaw = "\(serverAddress)/\(encodedShareName!)"` (with a  `!`)

Comment: It does not work with volumes of Swedish characters. It creates an empty folder in /Volumes/ with the correct name.
Here how it looks in the /Volumes/ with a working volume, and an unsuccessful installation:
`ls -l /Volumes/`

`dr-x------  1 magnus  staff  264  6 Nov 21:05 myVolume`

`d--x--x--x+ 2 magnus  wheel   68  6 Nov 21:03 myVolumeÅÄÖ`

Answer (score 0):

First, you should fix how you're building the URL. Use `NSURLComponents` instead of concatenating and escaping/quoting strings. Create an `NSURLComponents` from the server URL string, then set its `path` property from the share name, then get a URL object using its `url` property.

Second, you need to check the return code from `NetFSMountURLSync()` to get insight into why it's failing.

Third, the Swedish characters in your share name can be represented in two different ways. For example, "Å" might be a single Unicode character, U+00C5 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE. Encoded in UTF-8, that would be the bytes 0xC3 0x85. Or, it might be two Unicode characters: a plain A (U+0041 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A) followed by a combining ring above character (U+030A COMBINING RING ABOVE). The UTF-8 for that sequence would be 0x41 0xCC 0x8A.

The two different places in which you enter the character, Xcode's console pane vs. a Terminal window, could produce different actual characters for the same keystrokes. That would mean the URLs are not the same.

The same sort of thing applies to the other Swedish characters in your share name.

You can use funky techniques to get the right characters on your command line, such as using `$'\x41\xCC\x8A'` in `bash` to get the second form of "Å".

It's up to the file server as to whether it treats the two paths as the same. Your program will either have to be familiar with the server in question and convert to its convention, or try various normalization strategies (e.g. using `decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping` or `precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping`) as fallbacks if the mount attempt fails because the share name isn't right.

Comment: First. I built the URL with `NSURLComponents`. It works without Swedish characters. With Swedish character `NetFSMountURLSync()` give me return code 2 from both Xcode and the command line. It used the variant "U + 00C5 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE." in the url.

Second. When it fails, return code is 2.

Third. When I use my original code, and from the command line sends `myVolume$'\x41\XCC\X8A\x41\XCC\x88\x4f\XCC\x88'` it works, but not with `myVolume$'\XC3\x85\XC3\x84\XC3\x96'`.

Comment: Thank you, you had the answer to my question, but there will be some new issues to resolve... And I need to try on more servers.